# F# Finding the median without the length

Tags: f#

Im trying to prepare myself for an upcoming re-exam on functional programming. One of the questions I received completelty stumped me.

We are to write a function that takes a sorted list and returns the median value. We can assume the length of the list is not 0 and that it is odd. Ok now this is pretty easy, except we are not allowed to make an explicit second pass over the list to determine its length. No problem I can just use the .length function, except we are also not allowed to use any built-in functions.

This was what I did although I did use the .length function:

```
let median list = 
let rec helper list count =
    match list with
    |(x::_) when count=0 -> x
    |(x::xs) -> helper xs (count-1)
helper list (list.Length/2)
```

How would I go about getting the length in the required way in order to work out the median?

Comment: The way to solve this one is a "turtle and rabbit" strategy, where both start at the beginning of the list, and the "turtle" advances by 1 item each time while the "rabbit" advances by 2 each time. When the "rabbit" is at the end of the list, the "turtle" is at the middle. The answer given by @Lee implements just that: `xs'` is the "turtle" and `ctr'` is the "rabbit". I just figured I'd leave this comment to help you understand *how* Lee's answer works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a function for finding the second half of a list:

```
let secondHalf l =
        let rec aux xs ctr =
            match ctr with
            | _::_::ctr' ->
                match xs with
                | _::xs' -> aux xs' ctr'
                | [] -> failwith "should never happen!"
            | _ -> xs
        aux l l
```

you can then use this to find the median:

```
let sortedMedian xs = let (m::_) = secondHalf xs in m
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated